# Search in application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to find some values within my application, not only one class. 'Ctrl + F' helps only in case I want to search in particular class and not an application. How can I search in all application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Search > File (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and switch to File search tab); then you can search all files.

Comment: Is there a way to add this search option into popup menu, when You are clicking on a folder ? On fresh Eclipse 3.7 I had no this option I had in 3.5. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+h: seach in each opened project!